# I have some comma separated values in database column and I have a value to check if that value exists in those comma separated value in database

Tags: mysql, sql

**colleges table bellow**

| ID | Name | Courses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1,2,3,4,5 |

CourseID = 1;

```
q = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE Courses = CourseID";
```

that ID is an (int) value but I have some comma-separated values in the Courses column.

is there any way in SQL to solve this problem

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated values. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: everyone says that. but the data is already there I have no options

Comment: What's your question about this? The given query lists all colleges with `Courses = 1` - anything not working with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your table design and never store data as comma separated.

You could use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM colleges where FIND_IN_SET(1, Courses);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb757ea16eb0612dd2cd8365a01d5681)

If you have spaces after or before comma you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM colleges where FIND_IN_SET(1, REPLACE(REPLACE(Courses, ', ', ','), ' ,', ','));
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1d61f824696bb19e5750935c4607de0)

Comment: Note that FIND_IN_SET() does not work as expected if the comma-separated list contains spaces. I know the example data shown in the OP's question does not have any spaces, but this is something to remember.

Comment: to expand on @BillKarwin 's comment, find_in_set expects comma separated, not comma+space separated.  so if there are spaces after the commas you'd need e.g. `find_in_set(7, Courses) || find_in_set(' 7', Courses)` or `find_in_set(' 7',concat(' ',Courses))`, at which point the concat solution in the other answer (with spaces added) seems just as easy

Comment: @BillKarwin I updated the answer and added a solution for spaces , but this are ugly solution. If it was me I would change  db design

Answer (score 0):

I share @jarlh's view.  This is a very bad idea.

Having said that, you can still do something like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE CONCAT(',',courses,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', course, ',%')
```

Again, not a great way to store your data.

Just be careful of extra whitespace in the data and adjust as needed.

See @Ergest's answer for a nice MySQL specific approach.